# Recurring payments using PayPal REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel-4, paypal

I am using REST PayPal API in my Laravel project with the help of [this link.](http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/) and it is working fine. Now I need Recurring Payments using PayPal functionality in my project.

Comment: What do you mean by recurring payments. Also post your code that you have tried

Comment: recurring payments means auto payments after a fixed duration like paypal subscription.

Answer (score 0):

For REST API in PayPal you can use the billing-plans as describe in [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements). There is a lot of operation you can do with billing-plans and also you can create the plans without having the plan to be active.